# Regex matching a line when it exists or not

Tags: regex, ffmpeg

I'm trying to decipher the FFmpeg output with regular expressions, however I'm having problems as sometimes lines exist sometimes they do not, for example for files are audio files and do not have a video line.

Example text for video;

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 30000.00 (30000/1) -> 15.00 (15/1)
Input #0, avi, from 'making_of_divx5mp3.avi':
  Duration: 00:27:46.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 154 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 320x240 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 40 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

Example text for audio;

Input #0, ogg, from 'C:\examplemedia\Americanism_(Franklin_D._Roosevelt).ogg':
  Duration: 00:04:21.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 49 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: vorbis, 11025 Hz, mono, s16, 49 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified

My regular expression

> s{2}Duration[:]\s(?\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2})[.]\d{2}[,]\s{1}start[:]\s{1}\d{1,}[.]\d{6}[,]\s{1}bitrate[:]\s{1}(?\d{1,}\skb[/]s).+
>
> \s{4}Stream\s[#]\d[.]\d[:]\sVideo[:]\s(?\w+)[,]\s(?\w+)[,]\s(?\d{2,}[x]\d{2,}).+
>
> \s{4}Stream\s[#]\d[.]\d[:]\sAudio[:]\s(?\w+)[,]\s(?\d+\sHz)[,]\s(?(\d\schannels|mono))[,]\s(?\w+)([,]\s(?\d{2,}\skb[/]s)|)

I tried to solve the problem with a lack of lines by changing one to include (regex|) which should match NULL, but it breaks my regex which then returns nothing.  I thought this would work as expressions are read right to left.

```
(\s{4}Stream\s[#]\d[.]\d[:]\sVideo[:]\s(?<videocodec>\w+)[,]\s(?<pixelformat>\w+)[,]\s(?<resolution>\d{2,}[x]\d{2,}).+|)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you could split the string and work on each line separately. so you would loop through the lines and try to match them against a list of possible formats.

EDIT
ok to keep in one regex

separate the regexes for each line with an 'or' and surround in brackets. put a quantifier at the end. so it could match up to 3 lines matching any one of the different line formats.

(audio_regex|video_regex|other_regex){1,3}

Comment: Thought about that, but ideally I'd like to keep everything in one regex, a bit less code and hopefully tidier!?

Comment: I've tried that thanks, but reduced the quantifier to 2, however the video regex fails to capture anything.

Comment: well then you either tried it incorrectly, or are looking in the wrong capturing groups